# Measure of segregation that takes population-level proportions into account (modified entropy/Theil index)

Tags: entropy, group-differences

I am interested in a measure of segregation which allows for multiple groups and is maximized when group levels reflect the population as a whole (rather than equality of group size).

The best I have found is the Theil or entropy index:

$H_t=- \sum_{g=1}^n p_{t,g} \ln(p_{t,g})$

where:

$t$ is the tract, or area that contains the people of interest. There will be multiple tracts, and I wish to compare across tracts.

$g$ is a group in the set of groups $G$ over which I am looking at segregation. Ex: race/ethnicity

$p_{t,g}$ is the proportion of individuals in group $g$ and tract $t$

The issue I have with this is that $H_t()$ is maximized when all groups are equally represented in the tract. **What I am interested in is a function that is maximized when groups represent the population as a whole.** For example, if we see 4 groups: 1,2,3,4, and they are distributed such that they make up 10,20,30,40 percent of the population respectively, then I would like a function that is maximized when this occurs - not when I see 25,25,25,25.

Does such a measure exist (can be an entropy measure or another measure of multi-group segregation)? How might I modify the entropy equation to represent this?

Comment: The measure $(1/2) \sum |p_i - P_i|$ is $0$ when two sets of proportions are identical and  a maximum of $1$ when one $p_i$ is $1$ and a different $P_i$ is $1$. It has many names, and naturally the pre-factor is at choice. I think it's often used in demography, sociology, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you are looking for a function that measures the distance between $p_{t, g}$ and the proportion of individuals in group $g$ in the whole population, which we can call $q_g$.

The cross entropy can help you (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy):

$H(q, p)_t = -\sum_g q_g \log p_{t,g}$

This function will reach its **minimum** when $p_{t,g} = q_g$ for each group. So the tract with the smallest cross entropy would be the most similar to the whole population.

You said that you wanted a function that is maximised instead, when that happens. Then, you should remove the minus:

$L(q, p)_t = \sum_g q_g \log p_{t,g} $

this would be the average log-likelihood: the likelihood is the probability that we see the groups' numbers in the population, assuming they were generated picking randomly from the tract. This function takes the logarithm of that and is divided by the number of individuals in the population.

I think this should work well. You might need to make sure that $p_{t,g}$ is always bigger than zero. Otherwise the logarithm will be not defined. You can use pseudo-counts to fix that (adding a prior of one individual to each group).

It's worth mentioning that $L(p, q) \neq L(q, p)$. If you want a symmetric function, you can look into the Jensen-Shannon divergence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence.